# How can I use installed python packages in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

CMD:

C:>pip list

Package        Version

---

beautifulsoup4 4.0.0b4

imgkit         1.0.2

pip            19.2.3

setuptools     41.2.0

wheel          0.34.2

But how can I use this packages like imgkit and beautifulsoup4 in Pycharm?

Answer (score 1):

You can write the command "pip install <PACKAGE_NAME>" in the command line or just import it and Pycharm will ask you if you like to install this package.

Make sure that the python interpreter of your Pycharm project is the same running on your command line, if not it will not sync its kind of a headache, from experience.

Comment: Hi @Nadav he want to use packages not install packages.

Comment: Thank You. One more question.
I opened a new projekt in Pycharm. So which "New environment" should I choose?
Virtualenv or Pipenv? What is the difference between this options?

Comment: Yes, I want to use installed packages in pycharm. I already installed them with pip.

Comment: Hi @Dani it depend on you.. you can use anyone package but my recommendation is use pipenv becuase it will not ask you to set your environment every time.

Comment: And what should i choose as Pipenv executable?
Sorry but I'm a python newbie.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting up something like a Conda or virtual environment and install the packages inside the environment. Then you can [configure Pycharm interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add_new_project_interpreter) to point to the correct environment you have set up.

Answer (score 0):

please try below code...

like  if you want to use beautifulsoap so write in pycharm file..

```
from bs4 import beautifulsoap
```

Comment: Hi @Dani please check and let me know if any problem